# Return syntax quirk in R

Tags: r, syntax, return

You can make a function with the following code in R, omitting the brackets after the return command, but the return statement does not behave as expected and seems to do nothing:

```
> func <- function(x) { return; print(x) }
> func(1)
[1] 1
```

Including the brackets behaves as expected:

```
> func <- function(x) { return(); print(x)}
> func(1)
NULL
```

Why? Does a return statement without an argument serve a purpose, and, if not, why doesn't it cause an exception?

Comment: In the first case, the `return` is not doing anything as there is no argument and the function is not executed.  It is just like calling `return` on the console i.e. `func <- function(x) { print(return)};
 func(1)#
.Primitive("return")`
  In the second case, it have nothing inside the argument.  So it prints NULL

Comment: @akrun So in general does calling a function without any arguments just act as a no-op?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I guess so. For e.g. `f1 <- function(x) {print(mean)};f1(1)#
function (x, ...) 
UseMethod("mean")`

;

Comment: You are not calling `return` in the first example. What did you expect?

Comment: What I'm trying to get at is, if this does nothing, why is it even valid syntax? why doesn't it just a crash? does it have a purpose I'm unaware of?

Comment: `return` isn't a keyword in R and you can also override it. It's just a predefined function. Just naming a function without the `()` in R isn't an error; it does just nothing if inside a function and implicitly calls `print` at the console.

Comment: Let's say, you create a function in java script (easy to use in browser) `function greet(){
  console.log("World");
}` and then run `greet` and `greet()` The second one returns the value while the first one don't.  But, it won't crash anything

Comment: @nicola Ahhh, return is not a keyword. I guess I should have known that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can perhaps offer some insight.  In addition to it being legal in R to have a function by itself with no parameters, it is also legal to have a *variable* on a line with no assignments, function calls, etc.  Consider the following code snippet:

```
x <- c(1,2,3)
x
print(x)
print
```

Here is the output from that:

```
[1] 1 2 3
[1] 1 2 3
function (x, ...) 
UseMethod("print")
<bytecode: 0xbb87b8>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

In other words, from the console the default behavior for a variable or function by itself is to print information about that variable or function.  So there clearly is defined behavior in this case, and it seems to be that the function does not get called.  This makes less sense perhaps when this is happening inside another function, though it definitely seems that R has behavior defined for this.

Comment: When you name an object at the console, you implicitly call the `print` method on it. So `object` at the console is equivalent to `print(object)`. Since `print` is a generic function, it acts accordingly to the class of `object`. So, if you name a function at the console, `print.function` gets called.

Comment: @nicola Then maybe the behavior for what happens inside a function is to no-op.  My basic point was that such syntax seems to be legitimate R.

Comment: Sure it is. I couldn't see a point in the OP unless they missed that `return` is just a regular function and not a keyword. You are correct that just naming an object inside a function does nothing. This of course doesn't have anything to do with `return` specifically.

Answer (score 1):

`function(x) { return(); print(x) }` calls `return()` as a function. `function(x) { return; print(x) }` references `return` as an ordinary object. Here is the difference.

```
return # Just show the function body.
## .Primitive("return")
return() # Actually call the function.
## Error: no function to return from, jumping to top level
```